# ¿Por qué MYSQL no detecta todas las filas de mi csv al importar?

Tags: mysql

buen día, sucede que al importar un archivo de excel en formato CSV MS-DOS a mi MYSQL Workbench no se detectan todas las filas que yo tengo en mi archivo, tengo más de 65,000 registros y se me detectan solo 640, mi archivo tiene filas vacias, intente retirarlas, pero la respuesta es la misma, no se si el problema sean los tipos de datos, aunque he tratado de adaptarlos todos, hay alguna modificacion que tenga que hacerle a mi excel antes de subirlo para que esto no suceda, hay alguna razon por la que borre o no lea registros?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: habria que ver si la linea 641 no tiene un error que hace que se corte...

Comment: Hay varias maneras de importar csv a MySQL ¿Cómo lo haces tú?.